# blank page with no code or errors on blog

Tags: homepage, blog

I'm encountering some trouble moving a Wordpress installation from a development to a production server. The development server works just fine, but when moving to production the blog page suddenly stops working.

Homepage: http://www.elireview.com
Blog: http://www.elireview.com/blog/

The homepage and the sub-pages of the site work fine, but when in Settings > Reading I set posts to display on the homepage, it them stops working and /blog/ works like expected.

The page produces absolutely no HTML or error messages, and nothing is recorded to the server logs, so I am working blind here. I've tried just about every recommendation for "blank page" on the web, but I can't find any solution that works.

Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: How do you mean, you set posts to display on the homepage? Shouldn't they be displaying at /blog/?

Comment: When I use the settings in Settings > Reader to specify where I want the blog to display - it can be set to either the homepage or to a static page. No matter where I set it, the page that is supposed to show the blog is completely blank/empty.

Comment: What is on line 24 of `/wp-content/themes/eli-marketing/header.php`. Courtesy of : http://www.elireview.com/blog/blah

Comment: Line 24 is a conditional statement: 
 <?php if(is_page('2245') || $post->post_parent == '2245'): ?>
It's meant to take action if the header is rendering for a specific page or the children of a specific page. Not sure why it's throwing that error, but removing it does not fix the problem on the blog.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to read over this thread. There are step-by-step instructions on dealing with sub-folders and root URLs. It's not as simple as changing the settings in WP, you have to edit a couple files to make it work as well.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Giving_WordPress_Its_Own_Directory

Comment: Thanks for the pointer, but that's not the problem. WP is installed in the root - it's just that I want the blog to display on a page, not on the homepage.